# Where are create separeted VirtualHost in Apache compiled from source

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, debian

Because I have a lot of VirtualHosts in the file `/etc/apche247/conf/extra/httdp-vhost.conf`, this file is extensive and unorganized.

I know some ways to create the `VirtualHost` dynamic, but in the automatic installation of Apache (apt-get/yum/pacman install) using the **sites-enabled** folder.

However, with the compiled Apache such folders do not exist, and don't know a dynamic way (without the need to include the file in **httpd.conf**), to do this.

This is my Apache (2.4.7) folder:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apache247# ll
total 76
drwxrwxrwx  15 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 153 root root 12288 Jan 19 21:38 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 build/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 cgi-bin/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan 19 21:40 conf/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 error/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 11:38 htdocs/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 icons/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 include/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 21:37 logs/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jan 19 12:16 man/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root 12288 Nov 19 15:36 manual/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 19 21:30 modules/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Include` in your main config file.

To get Debian-like `sites-enabled`:

```
Include /etc/apache247/sites-enabled/*
```

Or RHEL-like conf.d:

```
Include /etc/apache247/conf.d/*.conf
```

(creating the directory for each as appropriate)